# Dependency problems upgrading to stretch: unable to open *.dpkg-new

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade, dpkg

I just tried to upgrade Debian using the instructions in [this website](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-debian-8-jessie-to-debian-9-stretch). The second time I ran upgrade (after rebooting, the first `upgrade` and `dist-upgrade` went well) the process stopped while installing `gnome-themes-standard-data_3.22.2-2_all.deb` with the error `unable to open '/usr/share/themes/Adwaita-dark/gtk-3.0/gtk.css.dpkg-new': No such file or directory`.

Apparently `.../Adwaita-dark/gtk-3.0/` is a symbollic link to `../Adwaita/gtk-3.0/`

**Relevant output:**

Fix-broken install:

```
root@a:/home/user# LC_ALL=C apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fonts-freefont-ttf gstreamer0.10-nice gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad libbasicusageenvironment0 libcdaudio1 libchromaprint0 libdirac-encoder0 libdvbpsi9 libgroupsock1 libgstreamer-plugins-bad0.10-0 liblircclient0
  liblivemedia23 libmimic0 libpostproc52 libprotobuf9 libslv2-9 libsoundtouch0 libswscale3 libusageenvironment1 libvncclient0 libwildmidi1 libxcb-composite0 vlc-nox
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  aptitude aptitude-common djvulibre-bin gir1.2-gepub-0.4 gir1.2-lokdocview-0.1 glib-networking glib-networking-common glib-networking-services gnome-documents gnome-system-monitor gnome-themes-standard-data
  libatkmm-1.6-1v5 libbasicusageenvironment1 libcairo-perl libcairomm-1.0-1v5 libclass-c3-xs-perl libcwidget3v5 libdvbpsi10 libebml4v5 libgd-perl libgepub0 libglib-perl libglibmm-2.4-1v5 libgnome2-canvas-perl
  libgnome2-perl libgnome2-vfs-perl libgnome2-wnck-perl libgoo-canvas-perl libgroupsock8 libgsf-bin libgtk2-imageview-perl libgtk2-unique-perl libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 libgtkmm-3.0-1v5 libjson-xs-perl
  liblibreofficekitgtk liblivemedia57 liblocale-gettext-perl libmatroska6v5 libmouse-perl libnet-dbus-perl libopenmpt-modplug1 libpangomm-1.4-1v5 libproxy-tools libproxy1v5 libqt5concurrent5 libqt5dbus5
  libqt5network5 libqt5opengl5 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5qml5 libqt5quick5 libqt5script5 libqt5sql5 libqt5sql5-sqlite libqt5test5 libqt5webkit5 libqt5x11extras5 libqt5xml5 libreoffice-gtk3 libreofficekit-data
  libsndio6.1 libsoprano4 libtext-iconv-perl libtext-soundex-perl libtypes-serialiser-perl libusageenvironment3 libuuid-perl libvlc-bin libvlccore8 libxapian30 libxml-parser-perl phonon-backend-vlc
  soprano-daemon vlc vlc-bin vlc-data vlc-l10n vlc-nox vlc-plugin-base vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-qt vlc-plugin-samba vlc-plugin-video-output
Suggested packages:
  apt-xapian-index debtags djvulibre-desktop libfont-freetype-perl libcwidget-dev qt5-qmltooling-plugins sndiod xapian-tools virtuoso-minimal libdvdcss2
Recommended packages:
  vlc-plugin-skins2 vlc-plugin-video-splitter vlc-plugin-visualization
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libatkmm-1.6-1 libcairomm-1.0-1 libcwidget3 libebml4 libebook-1.2-14 libebook-contacts-1.2-0 libedata-book-1.2-20 libfarstream-0.1-0 libglibmm-2.4-1c2a libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a libgtkmm-3.0-1 libmatroska6
  libpangomm-1.4-1 libphonenumber6 libproxy1 vlc-plugin-pulse
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gir1.2-gepub-0.4 gir1.2-lokdocview-0.1 libatkmm-1.6-1v5 libbasicusageenvironment1 libcairomm-1.0-1v5 libcwidget3v5 libdvbpsi10 libebml4v5 libgepub0 libglibmm-2.4-1v5 libgroupsock8 libgsf-bin libgtkmm-2.4-1v5
  libgtkmm-3.0-1v5 liblibreofficekitgtk liblivemedia57 libmatroska6v5 libopenmpt-modplug1 libpangomm-1.4-1v5 libproxy1v5 libqt5x11extras5 libreoffice-gtk3 libreofficekit-data libsndio6.1
  libtypes-serialiser-perl libusageenvironment3 libvlc-bin libxapian30 vlc-bin vlc-l10n vlc-plugin-base vlc-plugin-qt vlc-plugin-video-output
The following packages will be upgraded:
  aptitude aptitude-common djvulibre-bin glib-networking glib-networking-common glib-networking-services gnome-documents gnome-system-monitor gnome-themes-standard-data libcairo-perl libclass-c3-xs-perl
  libgd-perl libglib-perl libgnome2-canvas-perl libgnome2-perl libgnome2-vfs-perl libgnome2-wnck-perl libgoo-canvas-perl libgtk2-imageview-perl libgtk2-unique-perl libjson-xs-perl liblocale-gettext-perl
  libmouse-perl libnet-dbus-perl libproxy-tools libqt5concurrent5 libqt5dbus5 libqt5network5 libqt5opengl5 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5qml5 libqt5quick5 libqt5script5 libqt5sql5 libqt5sql5-sqlite libqt5test5
  libqt5webkit5 libqt5xml5 libsoprano4 libtext-iconv-perl libtext-soundex-perl libuuid-perl libvlccore8 libxml-parser-perl phonon-backend-vlc soprano-daemon vlc vlc-data vlc-nox vlc-plugin-notify
  vlc-plugin-samba
51 upgraded, 33 newly installed, 16 to remove and 528 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/43.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 4922 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Reading changelogs... Done
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
(Reading database ... 344160 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gnome-themes-standard-data_3.22.2-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-themes-standard-data (3.22.2-2) over (3.14.2.2-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/gnome-themes-standard-data_3.22.2-2_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/usr/share/themes/Adwaita-dark/gtk-3.0/gtk.css.dpkg-new': No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gnome-themes-standard-data_3.22.2-2_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Dpkg force install:

```
root@a:/home/user# LC_ALL=C dpkg -i --force-depends /var/cache/apt/archives/gnome-themes-standard-data_3.22.2-2_all.deb 
(Reading database ... 344160 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gnome-themes-standard-data_3.22.2-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-themes-standard-data (3.22.2-2) over (3.14.2.2-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/gnome-themes-standard-data_3.22.2-2_all.deb (--install):
 unable to open '/usr/share/themes/Adwaita-dark/gtk-3.0/gtk.css.dpkg-new': No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gnome-themes-standard-data_3.22.2-2_all.deb
```

Dpkg configure pending:

```
root@a:/home/user# LC_ALL=C dpkg --configure --pending --abort-after=2000
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-themes-standard:amd64:
 gnome-themes-standard:amd64 depends on gnome-themes-standard-data (= 3.22.2-2); however:
  Version of gnome-themes-standard-data on system is 3.14.2.2-1.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-themes-standard:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gparted:
 gparted depends on libatkmm-1.6-1v5 (>= 2.24.0); however:
  Package libatkmm-1.6-1v5 is not installed.
 gparted depends on libglibmm-2.4-1v5 (>= 2.50.0); however:
  Package libglibmm-2.4-1v5 is not installed.
 gparted depends on libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 (>= 1:2.24.0); however:
  Package libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 is not installed.
 gparted depends on libpangomm-1.4-1v5 (>= 2.40.0); however:
  Package libpangomm-1.4-1v5 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package gparted (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of inkscape:
 inkscape depends on libatkmm-1.6-1v5 (>= 2.24.0); however:
  Package libatkmm-1.6-1v5 is not installed.
 inkscape depends on libcairomm-1.0-1v5 (>= 1.12.0); however:
  Package libcairomm-1.0-1v5 is not installed.
 inkscape depends on libglibmm-2.4-1v5 (>= 2.50.0); however:
  Package libglibmm-2.4-1v5 is not installed.
 inkscape depends on libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 (>= 1:2.24.0); however:
  Package libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 is not installed.
 inkscape depends on libpangomm-1.4-1v5 (>= 2.40.0); however:
  Package libpangomm-1.4-1v5 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package inkscape (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gnome-themes-standard:amd64
 gparted
 inkscape
```

Dpkg --configure:

```
root@a:/home/user# LC_ALL=C dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-themes-standard:amd64:
 gnome-themes-standard:amd64 depends on gnome-themes-standard-data (= 3.22.2-2); however:
  Version of gnome-themes-standard-data on system is 3.14.2.2-1.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-themes-standard:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gparted:
 gparted depends on libatkmm-1.6-1v5 (>= 2.24.0); however:
  Package libatkmm-1.6-1v5 is not installed.
 gparted depends on libglibmm-2.4-1v5 (>= 2.50.0); however:
  Package libglibmm-2.4-1v5 is not installed.
 gparted depends on libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 (>= 1:2.24.0); however:
  Package libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 is not installed.
 gparted depends on libpangomm-1.4-1v5 (>= 2.40.0); however:
  Package libpangomm-1.4-1v5 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package gparted (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of inkscape:
 inkscape depends on libatkmm-1.6-1v5 (>= 2.24.0); however:
  Package libatkmm-1.6-1v5 is not installed.
 inkscape depends on libcairomm-1.0-1v5 (>= 1.12.0); however:
  Package libcairomm-1.0-1v5 is not installed.
 inkscape depends on libglibmm-2.4-1v5 (>= 2.50.0); however:
  Package libglibmm-2.4-1v5 is not installed.
 inkscape depends on libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 (>= 1:2.24.0); however:
  Package libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 is not installed.
 inkscape depends on libpangomm-1.4-1v5 (>= 2.40.0); however:
  Package libpangomm-1.4-1v5 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package inkscape (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gnome-themes-standard:amd64
 gparted
 inkscape
```

Upgrade:

```
root@a:/home/user# LC_ALL=C apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 adwaita-icon-theme : Breaks: gnome-themes-standard-data (< 3.18.0-2~) but 3.14.2.2-1 is installed
 aptitude : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 djvulibre-bin : Depends: libdjvulibre21 (= 3.5.25.4-4+b1) but 3.5.27.1-7 is installed
 gnome-documents : Depends: libgnome-desktop-3-10 (>= 3.11.90) but it is not installable
 gnome-system-monitor : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 gnome-themes-standard : Depends: gnome-themes-standard-data (= 3.22.2-2) but 3.14.2.2-1 is installed
 gparted : Depends: libatkmm-1.6-1v5 (>= 2.24.0) but it is not installed
           Depends: libglibmm-2.4-1v5 (>= 2.50.0) but it is not installed
           Depends: libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 (>= 1:2.24.0) but it is not installed
           Depends: libpangomm-1.4-1v5 (>= 2.40.0) but it is not installed
 inkscape : Depends: libatkmm-1.6-1v5 (>= 2.24.0) but it is not installed
            Depends: libcairomm-1.0-1v5 (>= 1.12.0) but it is not installed
            Depends: libglibmm-2.4-1v5 (>= 2.50.0) but it is not installed
            Depends: libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 (>= 1:2.24.0) but it is not installed
            Depends: libpangomm-1.4-1v5 (>= 2.40.0) but it is not installed
            Recommends: python-scour but it is not installed
 libatkmm-1.6-1 : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 libcairo-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.20.0 but it is not installable
 libcairomm-1.0-1 : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 libclass-c3-xs-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.20.0 but it is not installable
 libcwidget3 : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 libfarstream-0.1-0 : Depends: gstreamer0.10-plugins-good (>= 0.10.29) but it is not installable
 libgd-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.20.0 but it is not installable
 libglib-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.20.0 but it is not installable
 libglibmm-2.4-1c2a : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 libgnome2-canvas-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.20.0 but it is not installable
 libgnome2-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.20.0 but it is not installable
 libgnome2-vfs-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.20.0 but it is not installable
 libgnome2-wnck-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.20.0 but it is not installable
 libgoo-canvas-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.20.0 but it is not installable
 libgtk2-imageview-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.20.0 but it is not installable
 libgtk2-unique-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.20.0 but it is not installable
 libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 libgtkmm-3.0-1 : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 libjson-xs-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.20.0 but it is not installable
 liblocale-gettext-perl : PreDepends: perlapi-5.20.0 but it is not installable
 libmouse-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.20.0 but it is not installable
 libnet-dbus-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.20.0 but it is not installable
 libpangomm-1.4-1 : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 libphonenumber6 : Depends: libboost-date-time1.55.0 but it is not installable
 libqt5concurrent5 : Depends: libqt5core5a (= 5.3.2+dfsg-4+deb8u2) but 5.7.1+dfsg-3+b1 is installed
 libqt5dbus5 : Depends: libqt5core5a (= 5.3.2+dfsg-4+deb8u2) but 5.7.1+dfsg-3+b1 is installed
 libqt5network5 : Depends: libqt5core5a (= 5.3.2+dfsg-4+deb8u2) but 5.7.1+dfsg-3+b1 is installed
 libqt5opengl5 : Depends: libqt5core5a (= 5.3.2+dfsg-4+deb8u2) but 5.7.1+dfsg-3+b1 is installed
                 Depends: libqt5gui5 (= 5.3.2+dfsg-4+deb8u2) but 5.7.1+dfsg-3+b1 is installed
                 Depends: libqt5widgets5 (= 5.3.2+dfsg-4+deb8u2) but 5.7.1+dfsg-3+b1 is installed
 libqt5printsupport5 : Depends: libqt5core5a (= 5.3.2+dfsg-4+deb8u2) but 5.7.1+dfsg-3+b1 is installed
                       Depends: libqt5gui5 (= 5.3.2+dfsg-4+deb8u2) but 5.7.1+dfsg-3+b1 is installed
                       Depends: libqt5widgets5 (= 5.3.2+dfsg-4+deb8u2) but 5.7.1+dfsg-3+b1 is installed
 libqt5qml5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-3-2 but it is not installable
 libqt5quick5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-3-2 but it is not installable
 libqt5script5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-3-2 but it is not installable
 libqt5sql5 : Depends: libqt5core5a (= 5.3.2+dfsg-4+deb8u2) but 5.7.1+dfsg-3+b1 is installed
 libqt5sql5-sqlite : Depends: libqt5core5a (= 5.3.2+dfsg-4+deb8u2) but 5.7.1+dfsg-3+b1 is installed
 libqt5test5 : Depends: libqt5core5a (= 5.3.2+dfsg-4+deb8u2) but 5.7.1+dfsg-3+b1 is installed
 libqt5webkit5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-3-2 but it is not installable
 libqt5xml5 : Depends: libqt5core5a (= 5.3.2+dfsg-4+deb8u2) but 5.7.1+dfsg-3+b1 is installed
 libsoprano4 : Depends: libclucene-core1 (>= 2.3.3.4) but it is not installable
 libtext-iconv-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.20.0 but it is not installable
 libtext-soundex-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.20.0 but it is not installable
 libuuid-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.20.0 but it is not installable
 libxml-parser-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.20.0 but it is not installable
 vlc-nox : Depends: libtag1c2a (>= 1.9.1) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Dist-upgrade:

```
root@a:/home/user# LC_ALL=C apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 adwaita-icon-theme : Breaks: gnome-themes-standard-data (< 3.18.0-2~) but 3.14.2.2-1 is installed
 aptitude : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 djvulibre-bin : Depends: libdjvulibre21 (= 3.5.25.4-4+b1) but 3.5.27.1-7 is installed
 gnome-documents : Depends: libgnome-desktop-3-10 (>= 3.11.90) but it is not installable
 gnome-system-monitor : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 gnome-themes-standard : Depends: gnome-themes-standard-data (= 3.22.2-2) but 3.14.2.2-1 is installed
 gparted : Depends: libatkmm-1.6-1v5 (>= 2.24.0) but it is not installed
           Depends: libglibmm-2.4-1v5 (>= 2.50.0) but it is not installed
           Depends: libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 (>= 1:2.24.0) but it is not installed
           Depends: libpangomm-1.4-1v5 (>= 2.40.0) but it is not installed
 inkscape : Depends: libatkmm-1.6-1v5 (>= 2.24.0) but it is not installed
            Depends: libcairomm-1.0-1v5 (>= 1.12.0) but it is not installed
            Depends: libglibmm-2.4-1v5 (>= 2.50.0) but it is not installed
            Depends: libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 (>= 1:2.24.0) but it is not installed
            Depends: libpangomm-1.4-1v5 (>= 2.40.0) but it is not installed
            Recommends: python-scour but it is not installed
 libatkmm-1.6-1 : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 libcairo-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.20.0 but it is not installable
 libcairomm-1.0-1 : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 libclass-c3-xs-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.20.0 but it is not installable
 libcwidget3 : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 libfarstream-0.1-0 : Depends: gstreamer0.10-plugins-good (>= 0.10.29) but it is not installable
 libgd-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.20.0 but it is not installable
 libglib-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.20.0 but it is not installable
 libglibmm-2.4-1c2a : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 libgnome2-canvas-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.20.0 but it is not installable
 libgnome2-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.20.0 but it is not installable
 libgnome2-vfs-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.20.0 but it is not installable
 libgnome2-wnck-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.20.0 but it is not installable
 libgoo-canvas-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.20.0 but it is not installable
 libgtk2-imageview-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.20.0 but it is not installable
 libgtk2-unique-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.20.0 but it is not installable
 libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 libgtkmm-3.0-1 : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 libjson-xs-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.20.0 but it is not installable
 liblocale-gettext-perl : PreDepends: perlapi-5.20.0 but it is not installable
 libmouse-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.20.0 but it is not installable
 libnet-dbus-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.20.0 but it is not installable
 libpangomm-1.4-1 : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.2.0) but it is not installable
 libphonenumber6 : Depends: libboost-date-time1.55.0 but it is not installable
 libqt5concurrent5 : Depends: libqt5core5a (= 5.3.2+dfsg-4+deb8u2) but 5.7.1+dfsg-3+b1 is installed
 libqt5dbus5 : Depends: libqt5core5a (= 5.3.2+dfsg-4+deb8u2) but 5.7.1+dfsg-3+b1 is installed
 libqt5network5 : Depends: libqt5core5a (= 5.3.2+dfsg-4+deb8u2) but 5.7.1+dfsg-3+b1 is installed
 libqt5opengl5 : Depends: libqt5core5a (= 5.3.2+dfsg-4+deb8u2) but 5.7.1+dfsg-3+b1 is installed
                 Depends: libqt5gui5 (= 5.3.2+dfsg-4+deb8u2) but 5.7.1+dfsg-3+b1 is installed
                 Depends: libqt5widgets5 (= 5.3.2+dfsg-4+deb8u2) but 5.7.1+dfsg-3+b1 is installed
 libqt5printsupport5 : Depends: libqt5core5a (= 5.3.2+dfsg-4+deb8u2) but 5.7.1+dfsg-3+b1 is installed
                       Depends: libqt5gui5 (= 5.3.2+dfsg-4+deb8u2) but 5.7.1+dfsg-3+b1 is installed
                       Depends: libqt5widgets5 (= 5.3.2+dfsg-4+deb8u2) but 5.7.1+dfsg-3+b1 is installed
 libqt5qml5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-3-2 but it is not installable
 libqt5quick5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-3-2 but it is not installable
 libqt5script5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-3-2 but it is not installable
 libqt5sql5 : Depends: libqt5core5a (= 5.3.2+dfsg-4+deb8u2) but 5.7.1+dfsg-3+b1 is installed
 libqt5sql5-sqlite : Depends: libqt5core5a (= 5.3.2+dfsg-4+deb8u2) but 5.7.1+dfsg-3+b1 is installed
 libqt5test5 : Depends: libqt5core5a (= 5.3.2+dfsg-4+deb8u2) but 5.7.1+dfsg-3+b1 is installed
 libqt5webkit5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-3-2 but it is not installable
 libqt5xml5 : Depends: libqt5core5a (= 5.3.2+dfsg-4+deb8u2) but 5.7.1+dfsg-3+b1 is installed
 libsoprano4 : Depends: libclucene-core1 (>= 2.3.3.4) but it is not installable
 libtext-iconv-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.20.0 but it is not installable
 libtext-soundex-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.20.0 but it is not installable
 libuuid-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.20.0 but it is not installable
 libxml-parser-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.20.0 but it is not installable
 vlc-nox : Depends: libtag1c2a (>= 1.9.1) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Sources.list:

```
deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/usr/share/themes/Adwaita-dark/gtk-3.0/` was a symbolic link to `/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-3.0/`. After removing the symbolic link with `sudo rm /usr/share/themes/Adwaita-dark/gtk-3.0/` the package updater created this folder (not as a link anymore) and the installation process worked out well.

Creating the folders/file `mkdir /usr/share/themes/Adwaita/`, `mkdir /usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-3.0` or `touch /usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` wasn't enough.

Answer (score 1):

I use often `aptitude`, to navigate thru dependencies. Try to upgrade few packages at a time.

Check also local installed packages, which are often program no more available in Debian. Try to remove them.

On my toolbox I have the following commands:

- `dpkg --configure --pending`, often with the option `--abort-after=2000`. The Default 50 is unworkable.
- go to `/var/cache/apt/archives` and `dpkg -i --force-depends package_version.dpkg` (the file in in such directory). In this case I force installing a package (and with `-r` to remove a package, but in this case the package name, not the filename).  `--force-override` is also an other useful option.  These are sometime needed when there are some broken dependencies.  Usually with package names, it is obvious that replacing an entire series of package to the new version of a series of packages is the correct way to continue (we hope the new packages have correct dependencies each other, just a broken update path).

In any case, I finish with few `dpkg --configure --pending` and new `apt update`, so that the correct dependencies are finally fixed.

But you should do this with due care. You can really broken you system: When forcing install, try to lock in the same directory all packages with the same version, and try to install them together. Related packages, from a single source, have the same version, and big series have often unique version numbers (rarely you will see them at version 2.0).  Try not to force libc/glibc and fundamental packages you need for an emergency rescue of system.

Comment: I tried the commands in your toolbox without success (see update). Did you mean `--force-overwrite`? I couldn't find a `--force-override` option.

Comment: Yes, right.  It take time to find the packages with problems. Do you have the directory `/usr/share/themes/Adwaita-dark/gtk-3.0/, are there some broken links in this path?   Could you create it? Or delete the packages which use and require it (mark them down, and reinstall later). `grep usr/share/themes/Adwaita /var/lib/dpkg/info/*list` should give you which installed packages touched such path.

Comment: The directory exists and is completely empty. The only package touching that path is `gnome-themes-standard-data` itself and I can't remove it with apt-get. `dpkg -r --force-all` first and `apt-get upgrade` later doesn't change anything.

Comment: Ah, `...Adwaita-dark/gtk-3.0` is a symbolic link to `../Adwaita/gtk-3.0`. The problem is that `../Adwaita` does not exist.

Comment: The generic troubleshooting: do you have enough space on disks? Do you have several partitions in `/var` or and in `/usr`?  Try to force uninstall of gnome-themes-standard-data and force depends on packages who depend on it.

Comment: Just create Adwaita. No other packages will touch such dir. so it seems a bug in package, which doesn't create the required directories.

Comment: Creating Adwaita or any of the subfolders wasn't enough. I had to remove the symbolic link and then it worked. If you add it to your answer I'll accept it, if not I'll create a new answer with the relevant part (`rm ...`) so it is easier to find.

Comment: I think you can provide the answer. I answered (above) in a general way, but it is good to have a different answer with the particular case.